# Apache Parquet: human-readable encoding present?

Tags: avro, parquet

This question is inspired by the Avro Json Encoding: https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#Encodings

```
Avro specifies two serialization encodings: binary and JSON. Most applications will use the binary encoding, as it is smaller and faster.
But, for debugging and web-based applications, the JSON encoding may sometimes be appropriate.
```

Is there a similar way to store data in Parquet in a human-readable form? For debugging purposes.